# Exceeded Background Duration on Main Thread through no fault of my code

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, ipad, nstimer

The following code created a scenario with a Main-Thread timeout and a killed app. I don't understand exactly why.

This method was called by the main thread and according to the stack trace, this call is not synchronous (it is fired directly from main.m). Yet why does it take 20+ seconds to perform? Doesn't this event get dequeued *only* after the timer fires?

```
[fooObj performSelector:@selector(populate) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

Crash Log:

> Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 20.060 (user 20.060, system 0.000),
>   100% CPU  Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 19.438, 97% CPU
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0: 0
>   CoreFoundation                    0x3ad408b4 CFArrayGetFirstIndexOfValue
>   + 348
>
> 1   CoreFoundation                    0x3ad46e88 CFRunLoopRemoveTimer + 224
>
> 2   CoreFoundation                0x3ad46d00 CFRunLoopTimerInvalidate + 324
>
> 3   MyApp     0x00034b94 -[Container clear] (Container.m:147)
>
> 4   MyApp 0x000348aa -[Container populate] (Container.m:77)
>
> 5   MyApp 0x00034f62 -[BaseContainer populate] (BaseContainer.m:75)
>
> 6   Foundation                        0x35bfaa6a __NSFireDelayedPerform + 446
>
> 7   CoreFoundation                    0x3add45dc
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 12
>
> 8   CoreFoundation                    0x3add428c __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 268
>
> 9  CoreFoundation                 0x3add2efc __CFRunLoopRun + 1228 10
>
> 10 CoreFoundation                 0x3ad45eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
>
> 11  CoreFoundation                    0x3ad45d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
>
> 12  GraphicsServices                  0x391132e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
>
> 13 UIKit                          0x33f852f4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
>
> 14 MyApp                  0x000029c6 main (main.m:14)

Here is another crash for the same reason : MT timeout. (seems from the log that Thread 0 is waiting for it's own mutex to be freed. Deadlock or misreading of logs?)

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 20.060 (user 20.060, system 0.000), 100% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 18.175, 91% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:

> 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x32af50fc __psynch_mutexwait + 24
>
> 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x35e56124 pthread_mutex_lock + 388
>
> 2   CoreFoundation                    0x3ad46df8 CFRunLoopRemoveTimer + 80
>
> 3   Foundation                        0x35bfaa20 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 372
>
> 4   CoreFoundation                    0x3add45dc **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 12
>
> 5   CoreFoundation                    0x3add428c __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 268
>
> 6   CoreFoundation                    0x3add2efc __CFRunLoopRun + 1228
>
> 7   CoreFoundation                    0x3ad45eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
>
> 8   CoreFoundation                    0x3ad45d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
>
> 9   GraphicsServices                  0x391132e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
>
> 10  UIKit                             0x33f852f4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
>
> 11  Hearts of Space                   0x000029c6 main (main.m:14)
>
> 12  Hearts of Space                   0x00002980 0x1000 + 6528

Edit: Added the impl of clear and populate. As you can see there are no blocking calls.

```
- (void)clear
{
    self.m_msdData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:0];
    self.m_maItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
    self.m_mdItems = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];
    [m_timer invalidate];
    self.m_timer = nil;
    self.m_nsUrlConnection = nil;

    // zz Don't change the property state, in case an observer is already listening.
    m_nState = CS_UNPOPULATED;
}


- (CONTAINER_STATE)populate
{
    [self clear];

    self.m_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:TIME_OUT_SEC 
                                target:self 
                                selector:@selector(timeout) 
                                userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:NO];

    self.m_nState = CS_POPULATING;

    return CS_POPULATING;
}
```

Comment: The info you provide isn’t exactly rich… Can you a least show the calling site, and the implementation of `-[Container populate]`, and `-[Container clear]`?

Comment: I added the implementation of clear and populate. As you can see there are no blocking calls. [BaseContainer populate] just calls [Container populate].

Comment: I see. Could it be that the timer you are trying to `invalidate` isn’t valid anymore at that time? I would actually expect another behavior from that, but…